# trying to increase cell by 1 for each 'flag' value in a row on DB BROWSER for SQLITE

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, select

I'm trying to increase a cell in a row for each 'flags' that is equal to '2'.

To be more specific, I have a table that contains customer_numbers and corresponding product groups that can be flagged as {0: 'never used the product', 1:'inactive', 2:'active'}

So my column names looks like this{customer_no, GRP1, GRP2, GRP3, GRP4, GRP5 and there is another column that I create to have count as GROUP_ACTIVE_COUNT}

For each customer, I want to count how many product_groups they are active on.

As an example:

- customer 1's GRP1:1 GRP2:2 GRP3:0 GRP4:1 GRP5:2 ----> GROUP_ACTIVE_COUNT will be equal to 2
- customer 2's GRP1:2 GRP2:2 GRP3:0 GRP4:1 GRP5:2 ----> GROUP_ACTIVE_COUNT will be equal to 3
- customer 3's GRP1:2 GRP2:2 GRP3:2 GRP4:2 GRP5:2 ----> GROUP_ACTIVE_COUNT will be equal to 5
- customer 4's GRP1:1 GRP2:1 GRP3:1 GRP4:1 GRP5:1 ----> GROUP_ACTIVE_COUNT will be equal to 0
- customer 5's GRP1:0 GRP2:0 GRP3:0 GRP4:0 GRP5:0 ----> GROUP_ACTIVE_COUNT will be equal to 0

Here is what I have done so far:

```
 SELECT
     CUST_NO
    ,GROUP_ACTIVE_C
    ,GROUP_ACTIVE_COUNT
    ,CASE
        WHEN GRP1 = 2 THEN --DO SOMETGING LIKE GROUP_ACTIVE_COUNT = GROUP_ACTIVE_COUNT+1
        WHEN GRP2 = 2 THEN --DO SOMETGING LIKE GROUP_ACTIVE_COUNT = GROUP_ACTIVE_COUNT+1
        WHEN GRP3 = 2 THEN --DO SOMETGING LIKE GROUP_ACTIVE_COUNT = GROUP_ACTIVE_COUNT+1
        WHEN GRP4 = 2 THEN --DO SOMETGING LIKE GROUP_ACTIVE_COUNT = GROUP_ACTIVE_COUNT+1
        WHEN GRP5 = 2 THEN --DO SOMETGING LIKE GROUP_ACTIVE_COUNT = GROUP_ACTIVE_COUNT+1    
    ,GRP1
    ,GRP2
    ,GRP3
    ,GRP4
    ,GRP5
FROM XSELL_DATAMART
```

My main problem is that I cant create a variable in SQ LITE so that i can dump +1 in it and save it into each corresponding row :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple option is:

```
select
    x.*,
    (grp1 = 2) + (grp2 = 2) + (grp3 = 2) + (grp4 = 2) + (grp5 = 2) group_active_count
from xsell_datamart x
```

SQLite evaluates each condition as `1` if true and `0` if false, so suming the conditions gives you, as a result, an integer value that represents the count of satisfied conditions.